# Reusable canvas code?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to use several `canvas-es` with different values (see `data-percent`) with same reusable code block but "animation" makes it a little bit tricky. Im not sure how to make it reusable. Copy-pasting the same code over and over again is obviously a wrong move, I usually avoid it at any cost.

---

First thing is obviously to remove `id` and use `class` instead, then I could select all the `canvas`-es:

```
<canvas class="circle-thingy" width="120" height="120" data-percent="75"></canvas>
<canvas class="circle-thingy" width="120" height="120" data-percent="23"></canvas>
<canvas class="circle-thingy" width="120" height="120" data-percent="89"></canvas>

var allCircles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle-thingy');
```

But now comes the trickier part.. How about `canvas` JavaScript code? There's probably a very easy solution but I can't see it! Terrible time to quit smoking I guess (as always), brain is like shut down.

---

**What I tried:** `for loop` with `allCircles` list. Problem is that I cannot use `setInterval` and `clearTimeout` with this approach. Dynamic variable names? How do I reference them later?

---

**Here's my code with a single circle, try it.**

```js
// Get canvas context
var ctx = document.getElementById('my-circle').getContext('2d');
// Current percent
var currentPercent = 0;
// Canvas north (close enough)
var start = 4.72;
// Dimensions
var cWidth = ctx.canvas.width;
var cHeight = ctx.canvas.height;
// Desired percent -> comes from canvas data-* attribute
var finalPercent = ctx.canvas.getAttribute('data-percent');
var diff;

function circle() {
  diff = ((currentPercent / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  
  // Bottom circle (grey)
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#eee';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(60, 60, 55, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();

  // Percent text
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.font="900 10px arial";
  ctx.fillText(currentPercent + '%', cWidth * 0.5, cHeight * 0.5 + 2, cWidth);

  // Upper circle (blue)
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#0095ff';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(60, 60, 55, start, diff / 10 + start);
  ctx.stroke();

  // If has desired percent -> stop
  if( currentPercent >= finalPercent) {
    clearTimeout(myCircle);
  }
  currentPercent++;
}

var myCircle = setInterval(circle, 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="my-circle" width="120" height="120" data-percent="75"></canvas>
```

Feel free to use this code snippet in your own projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to solve this.

Create a helper function that will start animation for given `canvas`:

```
function animateCircle(canvas) {
    var scope = {
        ctx: canvas.getContext('2d')
        // other properties, like currentPercent, finalPercent, etc
    };        
    scope.interval = setInterval(circle.bind(scope), 20);
}
```

Change your `circle` function to refer variables from `this` instead of global ones:

```
function circle() {
    // your old code with corresponding changes
    // e.g.
    var ctx = this.ctx; // references corresponding scope.ctx
    // or
    this.currentPercent++; // references corresponding scope.currentPercent
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4db2r1mg/2/), if something is not clear.

Comment: You should not be using setInterval for animation, there are a host of problems associated with it that can cause poor quality animation (shearing, lagging, inconsistent frame rates, and unpredictable and unavoidable page crashes to name but a few). Use requestAnimationFrame for any sort of animation. It is synced to the display refresh, the browser understands that you are doing animation and thus will present the canvas/s without shearing, and will not attempt to render more than that device can handle per frame. It will give a much high quality animation across all platforms.